# Redux Form + Material UI - Async validation running on change instead of blur

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am using redux form with Material Ui. I want my async validation to fire only on blur (as is expected), however it is being fired on change.

#### My environment

node: v12.14.1,
npm: 6.13.4

npm packages

```
"material-ui": "0.20.2",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-redux": "7.2.0",
"redux": "4.0.5",
"redux-form": "^8.3.6",
"redux-form-website-template": "1.0.13"
```

#### Steps to reproduce

I downloaded the Material UI example from here https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/material-ui/
Then I updated all my packages (as my project has newer version of react and material UI).
To update my packages I did ran following from my root folder;

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm update
npm install
```

Then I start my project and inspect with redux tools.
Enter text into a text field (e.g: firstName)
@@redux-form/START_ASYNC_VALIDATION is trigged every-time a new character is entered.

Here is a sandbox of the project https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-material-ui-updated-8sos2?file=/package.json:141-312

#### Expected behaviour

I expect that when I change values in the form (e.g type a new character into the firstName field) only the change action (@@redux-form/CHANGE) is run. Then async validation action (@@redux-form/START_ASYNC_VALIDATION) is run when I blur a field. This is how original demo behaves (https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/material-ui/).

#### Actual behaviour

Action @@redux-form/START_ASYNC_VALIDATION is triggered every-time I change a field.

#### My Question

I am not sure is causing this is an issue. I think it could be;

1. A mistake I made in updating my packages
2. Versions of other packages that I am using (like my Material UI version) are incompatible
3. Some configuration is needed get redux form to beehive as I expect
4. An issue with redux form (I have opened an issue here https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/4678)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly share code snippet here - links to sandbox are cool but can't be guaranteed to stay around as long as this question lives.

Comment: In the future please always include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what fields to asynchronously validate on blur using the `asynchBlurFields` config.

[async validation](https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/asyncvalidation/)

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'MaterialUiForm',
  validate,
  asyncValidate,
  asyncBlurFields: ["email"],
})(MaterialUiForm);
```

[image: Edit Redux Form Material UI Updated]

Comment: Wow that did it. Thanks a lot. I guess that is a new property that wasn't around when the Material UI Demo was first made.

Comment: @SimonVerhoeven Oh, you're right, I didn't even think to look at the material-ui demo you linked, didn't realize it was a redux-form demo. If sufficiently resolved please feel free to accept answer.